# H2 Triggers behaving in infinite loop

Tags: java, triggers, sql-update, h2

I create a trigger for H2 database to automate the update of a timestamp column "updated_ts". That trigger behaves as an infinite loop when UPDATE sql statment is called.

```
UPATE main.doc doc SET 
value = 100.
WHERE doc.id = 1;
```

## Trigger infinite looping

```
@Override
    public void fire(Connection conn, Object[] oldRow, Object[] newRow) throws SQLException {
        
        log.debug(" FIRED Trigger for UpdateTimestamp table {}",
                this.schemaName.concat(".").concat(this.tableName));
        
        if(Objects.isNull(newRow))
            return;
        
        final Long id = (Long)newRow[0];

        log.debug(" FIRED Trigger for id {}", id);
        
        final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
        final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime
                .of(localDate.getDayOfYear(), localDate.getMonth(), localDate.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0, 0);
    
        final String update = new StringBuilder("UPDATE ")
                .append(this.schemaName).append(".")
                .append(this.tableName).append(" doc SET ")
                .append(" update_ts = ? ")
                .append(" where doc.id = ? ")
                .toString();
        
        final PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(update);

        statement.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime));
        statement.setLong(2, id);
        
        final boolean ok = statement.execute();
        
        log.debug("Update status {} for UpdateTimestampShippingcalcDoc id {} table {}",
                ok , id, this.schemaName.concat(".").concat(this.tableName));
    }
```

I think it's of H2 behavor

Comment: BTW, assuming `this,shemaName` is a String, `this.schemaName.concat(".").concat(this.tableName)` is easier to understand if written as `this.schemaName + "." + this.tableName` (eventually even faster)  || Also why use `StringBuilder` to create `update`?

Comment: BTW2 `LocalDate` has a `atStartOfDay()` method....

Comment: @user85421 It is best practice to use StringBuilder. StringBuilder helps with performance. "StringBuilder stands out as the fastest one, whereas String.format() is the slowest one" https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-concatenation-methods.

Comment: Paulo, that was true before Java 8 (10 years ago)  and only if concatenating (to the *same* string) in a loop. Before Java 8 `str1 + str2` was compiled similar to `new StringBuilder().append(str1).append(str2).toString()` , which is exactly what you are doing here - it would only be an advantage if the concatenation occurs in a loop, to avoid creating a new `StringBuilder` each iteration.

Comment: see [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1532461/85421) and maybe [Why use StringBuilder explicitly if the compiler converts string concatenation to a StringBuilder automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11942368/85421) || And probably there would be no detectable time difference compared to the database spent time; *normal* concatenation is just easier to read/maintain (IMHO)

Comment: (Oh, it is since Java 9 [7 years ago]; Java 8 is still using `StringBuilder`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write your trigger with ***AFTER*** SQL statement

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_timestamp_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON public.bill
    FOR EACH ROW
    CALL "loop.update.trigger.UpdateTimestamp";
```

I was using BEFORE

Answer (score 4):

No wonder why an infinite loop arises: A trigger handler is called by H2 every time a write operation is done in your table. So, if your code performs an UPDATE within the method, it will trigger the same handler on and on.

Do not include UPDATEs into your handler code: According to the [Trigger specification](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/Trigger.html#fire-java.sql.Connection-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-), you can modify the row values (**before** they get written) just by modifying the `newRow` cells.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Post the code where you tried to modify the newRow cells without performing UPDATEs to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use a trigger here, H2 has non-standard MySQL-style `ON UPDATE` clause and it can be used instead:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MAIN.DOC(
...
UPDATE_TS DATE
    DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_DATE
    DEFAULT ON NULL
    NOT NULL,
...
);
```

`DEFAULT` expression is used when a new row is inserted and no value for this column is provided, `ON UPDATE` expression is used when a row is updated and no new value for this column is provided, `DEFAULT ON NULL` converts passed null values to default values.

If you really need to use a trigger (for example, because your application tries to set own incorrect value of `UPDATE_TS` column and you can't avoid it for some reason), this trigger must just set value in the `newRow` array. But don't mess with legacy datetime API in triggers, they use JSR-310 data types in modern versions of H2. For `DATE` columns use `newRow[/*0-based-column-index*/] = LocalDate.now()`.

Comment: I can't update anything without looping infinitely. Example https://github.com/pddec/loop

Comment: Don't try to execute another `UPDATE` in the table from the trigger. You need to update values in the passed array (or `ResultSet`) directly.